# Is it possible to cut off a string before a certain symbol appears?

Tags: php, regex, string, base64

> $base64image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBOR(...)5CYII=";

I need to cut off the first part of the string and stop when the comma is cut off, 
so only "iVBOR(...)5CYII=" remains, since I'm using a function that doesn't support
the current format using the "data:image/;base64," at the beginning, I need it to be always cut off the string.

PS: The length of the string before the commas can differ :/

> How could I achieve this?

Comment: Search for the comma. Use that as the length to keep.

Comment: there are many ways `explode`, `substr($string, strpos($string, ',') + 1);`

Comment: Have you researched any documentation to do this?

Comment: yes the only part that caused me trouble is the fact that the length of the string before the comma might vary, otherwise it would have been easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$result = substr(strstr($base64image, ','), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of strpos, and substr like so...

```
$comma_pos = strpos($base64image,',');
$base64image = substr($base64image,$comma_pos + 1);
```

Comment: `$comma_pos + 1` unless you want to include the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Another one using [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
echo explode(",", $base64image)[1];
```

[outputs](https://eval.in/150640):

```
iVBOR(...)5CYII=
```